# Multiple image files and using file reader to preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, filereader

I have to upload multiple image file and I need to show the the preview of the image.
But the problem I'm facing using following javascript is image got changed when i upload the other image, means when i upload the `feature_image`, the `product_image` which i uploaded earlier being replaced by the new one and there is code redundancy there as i used same function for different different id, how do I solve the issue with optimized solution..Thanks in Advance

HERE is the HTML part:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Product Image</label>
      <input type="file" name="product_image"  id="product_image" width="200px">
      <img src="" id="product-img-tag" width="200px" />  
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Feature Image</label>
       <input type="file" name="feature_image"  id="feature_image" width="200px">
       <img src="" id="feature-img-tag" width="200px" /> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Slurp Image</label>
       <input type="file" name="slurp_image"  id="slurp_image" width="200px">
       <img src="" id="slurp-img-tag" width="200px" />    
</div>
```

Here is the javascript part :

```
   function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                  var reader = new FileReader();

                  reader.onload = function (e) {
                      $('#product-img-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
                  }
                  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
              }
          }
          $("#product_image").change(function(){
              readURL(this);
          });

                   function readURL(input) {
              if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                  var reader = new FileReader();

                  reader.onload = function (e) {
                      $('#feature-img-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
                  }
                  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
              }
          }
          $("#feature_image").change(function(){
              readURL(this);
          });

                   function readURL(input) {
              if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                  var reader = new FileReader();

                  reader.onload = function (e) {
                      $('#slurp-img-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
                  }
                  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
              }
          }
          $("#slurp_image").change(function(){
              readURL(this);
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Optimized solution :** don't use a FileReader, use the [`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method.

When the blobs passed to this method come from an `<input type="file">`, the URI returned is a direct pointer to the file on the user system, hence it is faster, less memory consumptive and easier to use (since synchronous) than a FileReader and its `toDataURL` method.

**Short version with your markup**

```js
// attach our event listener on all the inputs
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]').forEach(function(input){
  input.addEventListener('change', readURL);
  });

function readURL(evt) {
  // here we can use 'this', it will be the input
  var img = this.nextElementSibling;
  // not really needed in this case but it's a good habit to revoke the blobURI when done
  img.onload = function(){URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)};
  
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Product Image</label>
      <input type="file" name="product_image"  id="product_image" width="200px">
      <img src="" id="product-img-tag" width="200px" />  
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Feature Image</label>
       <input type="file" name="feature_image"  id="feature_image" width="200px">
       <img src="" id="feature-img-tag" width="200px" /> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Slurp Image</label>
       <input type="file" name="slurp_image"  id="slurp_image" width="200px">
       <img src="" id="slurp-img-tag" width="200px" />    
</div>
```

**Longer version** based on ids

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]').forEach(function(input){
  input.addEventListener('change', readURL);
  });

function readURL(evt) {
  var img_id;
  switch(this.id){
    case "product_image" : img_id = "product-img-tag"; break;
    case "feature_image" : img_id = "feature-img-tag"; break;
    case "slurp_image" : img_id = "slurp-img-tag"; break;
    }
  
  var img = document.getElementById(img_id);
  if(!img){
    return;
    }
  img.onload = function(){URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)};
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Product Image</label>
      <input type="file" name="product_image"  id="product_image" width="200px">
      <img src="" id="product-img-tag" width="200px" />  
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Feature Image</label>
       <input type="file" name="feature_image"  id="feature_image" width="200px">
       <img src="" id="feature-img-tag" width="200px" /> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Slurp Image</label>
       <input type="file" name="slurp_image"  id="slurp_image" width="200px">
       <img src="" id="slurp-img-tag" width="200px" />    
</div>
```